# Problem with new popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this bellow program if you click on 'PRINT', the html content of  will be added to new popup window called b.html. It is working fine, but b.html has some html content and i am losing this data when new popup window opened. Without missing html content of b.html how can i append new html content inside  .

My Sample Code:

**Page Name: a.html**

```
                <html>
                     <head>
                          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js">  </script>
                          <script type="text/javascript">
                               $(document).ready(function()
                               {
                                    $("#print").click(function()
                                    {
                                         var newWind=window.open('b.html', 'Print message',"left=100,screenX=200,menubar=yes, width=980,height=500, location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes");
                                         var printableHTML=$("#msg").html();
                                         newWind.document.write(printableHTML);
                                         //newWind.append(printableHTML);
                                    });
                               });
                          </script>
                     </head>
                     <body>
                          <span id="print"><u>PRINT</u></span>

                          <div id="msg">
                             <h4>  I am printing this message...</h4>
                          </div>
                     </body>
                </html>
```

**Page Name: b.html**

```
           <html>
                <head> </head>
                <body>
                    <h4>Hello</h4>
                    <div id="target"></div>
                </body>
           </html>
```

Comment: If your post a wall of code, it's appreciated if you make a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) link!

Comment: What browser? Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pPdwC/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `document.write` after the page has loaded, you are replacing the document.

Use load event of the window, so that you can access the content of the document once it has loaded:

```
$(newWind).load(function() {
  $('#target', newWind.document).html(printableHTML);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of popping up a new window and populating it with the bits you're wanting to print, a better solution would be to print as standard `window.print()` and use a print media stylesheet to show/hide the portions of the page you want printable.

```
@media print {
  /* style sheet for print goes here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var newWind=window.open('b.html', 'Print message', ...
```

to

```
window.open('b.html', 'Print_message', ...
```

Then you can do

```
Print_message.document.write(printableHTML);
```